# Issue loading webpack 2 library with shared vendor (webpack 2 & Angular 2)

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I have a normal angular 2 application being compiled with webpack 2 (working) and I am compiling a separate webpack library (working) that references the same version of angular but will be loaded at runtime using a script loader.

I load the compiled library, it begins executing, but then runs into the following:

> Cannot read property 'Component' of undefined

The 'Component' it is trying to load is the one provided by @angular/core in the calling angular 2 application (this has been loaded as the root application is making use of it).

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
```

As far as I can tell when loading the compiled library the internal webpack_require is not syncing with the root application and informing it that the @angular components have been loaded.

My webpack config:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    entry: {
      app: "./src/app/main.ts",      // The root application
      vendor: "./src/app/vendor.ts"  // The file containing the @angular vendor files
    },
    module: ...,
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build/dev")
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        names: ["app", "polyfills"]
      }),
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        "./src",
        {}
      ),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: "src/index.html"
      })
    ]
  },

  {
    entry: {
      "module/dashboard/dashboard": "./src/module/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts"
    },
    externals: [
      "@angular/common",
      "@angular/compiler",
      "@angular/core",
      "@angular/forms",
      "@angular/http",
      "@angular/platform-browser",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic",
      "@angular/router"
    ],
    module: ...,
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    output: {
      filename: "[name].js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../build/dev"),
      library: "DashboardModuleLibrary",
      libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
        /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
        "./src",
        {}
      ),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    ]
  }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have a silly question: where is your entry for polyfills? Am I just not seeing it?

Comment: Sorry it is there, I just removed it so the example was just focusing on the items being discussed.  `entry: {
      app: "./src/app/main.ts",
      polyfills: "./src/app/polyfills.ts",
      theme: "./src/app/theme.ts",
      vendor: "./src/app/vendor.ts"
    },`